# stuck on deriving Cauchy product

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Could someone give me some heads up help or hint as to how I go from the LHS of the inequality to the other?$$\sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^{2n} {\sum\limits_{j = k - n}^n {{c^2}{r^{ - k}}{{\left| {z - {z_0}} \right|}^k} \le } } \sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^{2n} {(2n - k + 1){c^2}{q^k} \le {n^2}{c^2}{q^{n + 1}}}$$ where $q: = \left| {z - {z_0}} \right|/r \prec 1$. I believe that I understand how the part in the parentheses, () and the $q^k$ come about but don't get the last inequality.
$$\begin{array}{l}\text{I see the sum goes from }k - n\text{ to }n\text{ so}\\\text{there are }n - k + n + 1\text{ terms, namely }\\\text{there are  }2n - k + 1\text{ terms which is in the parentheses}\text{.}\\\text{The outer sum working on this}\end{array}$$

$$\begin{array}{l}\sum\limits_{n + 1}^{2n} {} \text{ there are n terms}\text{. }\\\sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^{2n} {(2n - k + 1)}  = 2\sum\limits_{}^{} n  - \sum\limits_{}^{} k  + \sum\limits_{}^{} 1  = 2{n^2} - n - \sum\limits_{}^{} k \\ \le 2{n^2}\end{array}$$
It comes from here, Proof of Cauchy product: Elias Wegert (auth.) - Visual Complex Functions_ An Introduction with Phase Portraits (2012, Birkhäuser Basel)
[image]

[image: Elias Wegert (auth.) - Visual Complex Functions_ An Introduction with Phase Portraits (2012, Birkhäuser Basel)]

Comment: You should not put text in an array of avoidable (and here it is very avoidable). The formatting is suboptimal, and you have many additional lines of text that don’t contribute to the post.

Comment: Okay, I think I've edited your post correctly. If you see any mistakes, please fix them.

Comment: I have added more and changed the title. Does this now conform to required standard?

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}{l}\text{Since }\sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^{2n} {} \text{ : implies }k \ge n + 1\\\text{Also since }q \prec 1\text{ (hyp)}\\{q^k} \le {q^{n + 1}}\\\sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^{2n} {} \text{ has n terms (i}\text{.e}\text{. 2n - n - 1 + 1)}\\\text{therefore, }\sum\limits_{k = n + 1}^{2n} {(2n - k + 1)}  \le n.n = {n^2}\\\text{since, }\\(k \ge n + 1 \Leftrightarrow  - k \le  - n - 1 \Leftrightarrow 2n - k + 1 \le 2n - n = n)\end{array}
%
$